# About basic combinatorics results

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I am trying to express some basic combinatorics results using finite sequences and functions. The following is what I have done:

Below $A,B$ are two sets with $m$ and $n$ elements, respectively.

We use $\color{red}{|X|}$ to denote that cardinality a the set $X$.

---

**Permutation:**

- $\big|\big\{(a_1,\cdots,a_n)\in A^n:(\forall i\neq j)(a_i\neq a_j)\big\}\big|=m!\binom{n}{m}$
- $\big|\big\{f\in B^A:f\text{ is injective}\big\}\big|=m!\binom{n}{m}$

---

**Combinations:**

- I didn't find a set containing finite sequences whose cardinality equal $\binom{n}{m}$
- $\big|\big\{f\in B^A:f\text{ is strictly increasing }\big\}\big|=\binom{n}{m}$

---

**Permutation with repetition:**

- $\big|\big\{(A_1,\cdots,A_n):(\forall i)( |A_i|=k_i)\wedge \cup_{i=1}^nA_i=\{1,\cdots,k\}\big\}\big|=\frac{k!}{k_1!k_2!\cdots k_n!}$
- I didn't find a set containing functions whose cardinality equal $\frac{k!}{k_1!k_2!\cdots k_n!}$

---

**Combination with repetition:**

- $\big|\big\{(x_1,\cdots,x_n)\in \mathbb{N}_0^n:x_1+\cdots+x_n=m\big\}\big|=\binom{n+m-1}{m}$
- $\big|\big\{f\in B^A:f\text{ is non-decreasing}\big\}\big|=\binom{n+m-1}{m}$

---

**First question:** Are what I wrote above correct?

Taking into consideration my goal (which is probably clear), **I ask**:

1. Could you please provide a set which contains *finite sequences* and with cardinality $\binom{n}{m}$? (See "Combinations" above)
2. Could you please provide a set which contains *functions* and with cardinality $\frac{k!}{k_1!k_2!\cdots k_n!}$? (See "Permutation with repetitions" above)

If anyone knows better examples than the ones I wrote above, please let me know!

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: What you are calling permutation with repetition is actually the number of [permutations of a multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_of_multisets).  A [permutation with repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_of_multisets) is a sequence of $m$ elements drawn from a set with $n$ elements with repetition, of which there are $n^m$.  $n^m$ is also the count of the number of functions from a set with $m$ elements to a set with $n$ elements.

Comment: What you wrote in your comment does not make sense to me.  Why are you adding up all the terms in the sequence in your numerator?  You may find this article about the [twelvefold way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way) instructive.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig The function $f:\{1,\cdots,k\}\to \mathbb{N}_0$ is a multiset and $f(i)$ is the multiplicity of the element $i$. That's why I got to that equality.